# Hola hay alguna forma en angular de hacer un select, con un input para buscar en sus registros?

Tags: html, angular, formularios

He estado buscando y solo vi algo que se llamada select2 pero no se como implementarlo en angular, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Existe el `datalist` en html.

Comment: Necesito que el value y lo que salga sean distintos, no quiero que salga la id mas el nombre del campo, puedo hacer que se muestre como un select?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `datalist`

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input


 list="browsers" name="myBrowser"  (change)="seleccionar($event)" /></label>
<datalist 

id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

Para obtener el valor tienes que hacer esto:

```
seleccionar(e) {
    //Obtener el valor
    console.log(e.srcElement.value);
  }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4nfxm)

## [Ejemplo aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/data-list)

Te paso un ejemplo de un codigo que hize para simular el datalist. Esta algo enredado, pero de ejemplo sirve.

Comment: ¿Hay forma de hacer que el Valúe y lo que se muestre no sea igual?, Estoy cargando el opción con la base de datos y en el valúe me gustaría que contuviera la id del registro y en lo que se muestre, que contuviera el nombre de este.

Comment: El `datalist` no permite mandar otro valor diferente al que se muestra. Puedes hacer uno propio.

Comment: En seguida te comparto un ejemplo

Comment: Vale muchas gracias me salvasste

Comment: @ÁlvaroGironaCutillas Listo, espero que te sirva.